# How to send a dynamic variable between two Python files?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to pass a variable from `graphics.py` to `core.py` .

`graphics.py`

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def xcross(x, y):

    cross = turtle.Turtle()
    #some code....
    global w
    w = cross.xcor()
```

`core.py`

```
import turtle
import graphics

print(graphics.w)
```

This variable(`w` in `graphics.py` changes its value each time I click a mouse button (not part of the question, but it's better you know it).

When I execute it, it's only passing the variable once and doesn't pass the variable again with it's value changed. The value it passes to the `core.py`  is `0`.(only once)

How do I make sure, I'm able to access this variable each time it's value changed(from `core.py`) and it doesn't remain `0`

Comment: You should store the variable in graphics.py and add a getter function (e.g., `get_w()`) and then you call this getter every time you need the w value in core.py.

Comment: Can you please elucidate?

Comment: What you have shown makes w the exact same in both modules - including changes. What you have not shown is how you write to x multiple times. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example for your problem.

Comment: If you need to share data between code in one module and code that uses it in another module, you should either pass that data as a function argument/return it from a function, or make the first module encapsulate it in a class. Don't try to use global variables to share mutable state between modules; it won't work.

Comment: Yes, I'm not able write the value of w to core.py multiple times. That's the problem here. And to add to it, it's printing 0. I'm not sure why that's happening.

Comment: @NotMyName yes, take a look at my answer and post any comments if required.

Comment: Please add the code for writing and reading multiple times! You current only show code for reading once and don’t use the code for writing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, variables should be restricted to each python file. If you need to share them, add a getter method to retrieve the value from the other file.

Considering your example, I have added a `get_w()` method on the `graphics.py` file that is used on the `core.py` file.

**graphics.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def xcross(x, y):
    cross = turtle.Turtle()

    # Some code...

    # W modification
    global w
    w = 1

def xcross2(x,y):
    # Some code...

    # W modification
    global w
    w = 2

def get_w():
    return w
```

**core.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# For better print formatting
from __future__ import print_function

# Imports
import turtle
from graphics import get_w

# Code
def core_func():
    print(get_w())
```

**Example main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Imports
import graphics
import core

# Code
def main():
    graphics.xcross(1, 2)
    core.core_func()                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    graphics.xcross2(1, 2)
    core.core_func()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Run:**

```
python main.py
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
```

Notice that the `core.py` code is inside a function now to be able to call it from the `main.py` but you might keep it as you had in your example. Also, I have copied the `xcross` method to show how the `w` value is modified and you can still get it from the `core.py` file. In your real application, you might keep a single `xcross` method and do the `w` modifications where required.

Answer (score 0):

graphics.py

```
import turtle
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def xcross(x, y):

    cross = turtle.Turtle()
    #some code....
    w = cross.xcor()
    return w
```

core.py

```
import turtle
import graphics

print(graphics.xcross(0, 1))
```